# $_GET[...] not working - database not updating

Tags: php, get

I've asked a few questions about this piece of code on this site.

Basically, my database is not updating when I use - $id = $GET_['id']; (at the top of the code below). The id gets passed to this page from the previous page - the url of the page is 'http:// www.21orange.com/CCC/changepassword.php?id=1'. There is an 'id' field in my database.

When I change the above line of code to - $id = '1' - the code runs perfectly and the database is updated. It only stops working when I use the $GET_['id']. Why is this?

```
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

  $id = $_GET['id'];

// This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
// If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{  
    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { 
        die("Please enter a password."); 
    } 

    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
    if(empty($_POST['confirmpassword'])) 
    { 
        // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
        // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
        // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
        // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
        die("Please confirm your password."); 
    } 

     if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {

    // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
    // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
    // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
    $query = "UPDATE Staff SET password=:password, salt=:salt WHERE id=:id"; 

    // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
    // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
    // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
    // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read. 
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

    // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
    // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
    // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
    // password cannot be recovered from the hash. 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
    // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
    // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
    // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
    // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    }  

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(array(
        'password' => $password,
        'salt' => $salt,
        'id' => $id));
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
    header("Location: stafflist.php");

     // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
    die("Redirecting to stafflist.php"); 

}

die("Passwords do not match.");  
}
```

I'm new to php, so forgive my naivety. P.s. I know the method I'm using is fairly old school, but it's only a test.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Is it generating an error, using one of your error messages, or just silently failing?

Comment: Why do you use `GET` for the `id`, but `POST` for everything else?

Comment: Hot tip: **enable error reporting** -- add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: No error. Just not working. I use POST as I have a form on the page containing the 'password' and 'confirmpassword' inputs. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I got this error:

Undefined index: id in /home/content/47/11368447/html/CCC/changepassword.php on line 6

Comment: @user2796717: Which means `$_GET['id']` doesn't exist. Note that it's case sensitive. So `ID` won't work.

Comment: @AmalMurali That's strange as I have used $_GET['id'] on other pages and it works perfectly. id is lower case in the url as well as the database, so what is the problem?

Comment: @JoeMorgan: Try adding `print_r($_GET);` to the top of your script and see what it outputs when you reload the page with the `id` query paramter.

Comment: @AmalMurali I receive this error:

Array ( [id] => 1 ) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/47/11368447/html/CCC/changepassword.php:2) in /home/content/47/11368447/html/CCC/common.php on line 78

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/47/11368447/html/CCC/changepassword.php:2) in /home/content/47/11368447/html/CCC/common.php on line 86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do both `GET` and `POST` in a single [HTTP Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

However, you can use an hidden input field to get around this limitation:

In your HTML markup, you can add the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id"
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

And your `$_GET['id']` should work just fine.

Comment: Did you put the parameter in the form 'action' as www.21orange.com/CCC/changepassword.php?id=1 . Yes you can' t do both GET and POST in a request but you can have both $_GET and $_POST with values.

Comment: @DavidLin: That won't work since the IDs will be different every time. It's *possible* with JavaScript, but this looks like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

To avoide this error

```
Undefined index: id in /home/content/47/11368447/html/CCC/changepassword.php on line 6
```

first test if the `index` exists :

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    // here you can set a value for the id
}
```

Otherwise, you can add your `$id` var in your if test :

```
if(!empty($_POST) && $id) 
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've replaced $id = $_GET['id']; with the above. I am now getting the same error but on a different line - 'id' => $id));.

Comment: thats normal. `id` is undefined on that line. See my updated answer !

Comment: but now I cannot use $id anywhere in my code. How can I get $id to equal the id sent from the previous page?

Comment: This just hides it, but doesn't answer the actual question that was asked.

Comment: @DavidLin answer's may help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the 'id' to the action URL but for some reason the $_GET variable is not having it. Please double check:

1. Are you really passing the 'id' to the URL ? Please make sure.
2. Please check the code in common.php to see if the $_GET variable is modified in it.
3. Is that script behind a rewrite settings (e.g in .htaccess) ? if yes, $_GET parameters could be gone due to inappropriate rewrite settings. You can further test it out by putting  print_r($_GET); in the beginning and visit that script directly ( GET instead of POST )

Comment: (As stated below) when I echo the $id at the top of the page, it displays correctly, after it gets is from the url. It just doesn't use the $id in the query's

Answer (score 0):

$id = $_GET['id'];
first check there is any value in $id to print the $id through echo

Comment: When I echo the $id it displays the correct id at the top of the page.